# chaining methods and properties in coffescript

Tags: coffeescript

What would be the best method to DRY out or chain this code using Coffeescript?

```
canvas=$('canvas')
canvas.getContext('2d').fillStyle='rgba(255,255,255,0.7)'
canvas.getContext('2d').font = "40px Verdana"
canvas.getContext('2d').fillText('alkatsa.com',canvas.width/2 - 120,canvas.height - 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there’s no chaining of properties, only of methods. I’d make variables for context, width and height. This would make code more vertical:

```
canvas = $ 'canvas'
{width, height} = canvas
context = canvas.getContext '2d'

context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'
context.font = '40px Verdana'
context.fillText 'example.com', width / 2 - 120, height - 50
```